# two instances of JButton overlapping

Tags: java

i have a class that makes a JButton with a string for text and a runnable for the OnClicked code:

```
public class WButton extends JButton implements MouseListenener 
MouseMotionListener {

    Runnable Clicked;

    public WButton(String s, Runnable r) {
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setText(s);
        Clicked = r;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Clicked.run();
    }
(other listeners)

}
```

and i ran this code to add two instances of the button:

```
public Main() {
    super();
    getContentPane().add(new WButton("Button 2", () -> {
        System.out.println("test");
    }));
    getContentPane().add(new WButton("Button 2", () -> {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }));
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

and it just showed the second button, not the first.
help?

Comment: @Yoda i ran it from the main it is the name of the class

Comment: Change the names of the buttons.  If `Main` is a `JFrame`, you've just added both buttons to the same position, but only the second is visible.  You could change the layout manager to something like `FlowLayout`